# how to determine if two circle segments live in the same sphere intersect with each other

Tags: math, geometry

curve *a* and *b* are two great circle segments that lie on a sphere. How can I decide whether these two circle segments intersect with each other?

Comment: How are these circles specified ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need only a fact of intersection, not intersection point (in the second case just look at `Intersection of two paths given start points and bearings` section of link below)

Let we have points `a1, a2, b1, b2` in lat/lon coordinates.

Paths `a1a2` and `b1b2` do intersect, if both `b1` and `b2` lie in different hemispheres relative to `a1a2` big circle, and `a1` and `a2` lie in different hemispheres relative to `b1b2` big circle.

To determine hemisheres, we can calculate signs of cross-track distances as described in `Cross-track distance` of [this page](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
Sign_(pt1, pt2, pt3) = sign(δ13) ⋅ sign(θ13−θ12)

where   δ13 is (angular) distance from start point to third point
θ13 is (initial) bearing from start point to third point
θ12 is (initial) bearing from start point to end point
```

So check that

```
 Sign_(a1, a2, b1) != Sign_(a1, a2, b2)
 Sign_(b1, b2, a1) != Sign_(b1, b2, a2)
```

Angular distance (Haversine formula):

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude
```

Bearing:

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )

where   φ1,λ1 is the start point, 
        φ2,λ2 the end point 
        (Δλ is the difference in longitude)
```

Comment: One detail seems to be missing in this interesting approach: two points on a sphere do not uniquely define a great circle segment. There are two great circle segments with the same end points that add up to the containing great circle.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you know the angle between the planes containing the circles as well as their distance to the center of the sphere (equivalently, the radii); the problem can be solved in 2D: make one of the planes horizontal and the intersection of the two planes in the viewing direction. What you see is an angle formed by two lines (traces of the planes), one being horizontal. You have all needed information to establish the equations of the lines and find the intersection point. Check if it belongs to the apparent outline of the sphere.

[image]